# Why does my parser not understand "numb=" properly?

Tags: python, compiler-errors

I tried to add a new 'NUMB=' to my WMC project but it won't work.
Mainly this

```
    elif Command[P] == "numb=":
         Running = "set_int"
    elif Running == "set_int" and Running == "":
        if Command[P] != "0" or Command[P] != "1" or Command[P] != "2" or Command[P] != "3" or Command[P] != "4" or Command[P] != "5" or Command[P] != "6" or Command[P] != "7"or Command[P] != ""or Command[P] != "8" or Command[P] != "9" or Command[P] != "10":
            print("The integer must not be bigger then 10, or be a string.")
            NUM = "0"
        else:
            NUM = Command[P]
```

and I do not understand, when I compare it to the "display" command I see nothing wrong. See:

```
elif Command[P] == "display" and Running == "":
    Running = "display"
elif Running == "display":
    print(Command[P])
```

I tried to compare them and debug the error myself. Now there is no python error, but it will not work the way I want.

```
while Loop == 1:
    P += 1 
    In = input(">")
    if In == " ":
        continue
    else:
        Command.append(In)
    if Command[P] == "END()":
        if Running != "":
            Running = ""
        elif Running == "":
            print("Closing...")
            exit()
    elif Command[P] == "display" and Running == "":
        Running = "display"
    elif Running == "display":
        print(Command[P])
    elif Command[P] == " ":
        continue
    elif Command[P] == "numb=":
         Running = "set_int"
    elif Running == "set_int" and Running == "":
        if Command[P] != "0" or Command[P] != "1" or Command[P] != "2" or Command[P] != "3" or Command[P] != "4" or Command[P] != "5" or Command[P] != "6" or Command[P] != "7"or Command[P] != ""or Command[P] != "8" or Command[P] != "9" or Command[P] != "10":
            print("The integer must not be bigger then 10, or be a string.")
            NUM = "0"
        else:
            NUM = Command[P]
```

I was expecting the command to set the variable to a string that is a number but instead it acts as if I didn't run the command.

Answer (score 1):

Take another look at what you wrote:

```
elif Running == "set_int" and Running == "":
```

When will this ever be True?